# Make notifications vibrate

Tags: samsung, audio, vibration, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I have an S9+. How do I simultaneously enable vibrations for notifications and ring volume for calls? When the phone is in vibrate mode, if I make the ring volume nonzero then the vibration mode is ended, disabling notification vibrations.